# Running shell commands in Swift

Tags: macos, bash, swift, shell

I'm trying to run shell commands using Swift in my OSX app.

Running basic commands such as echo work fine but the following throws

"env: node: No such file or directory"

```
@IBAction func streamTorrent(sender: AnyObject) {
  shell("node", "-v")
}

func shell(args: String...) -> Int32 {
    let task = NSTask()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    task.arguments = args
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
}
```

I also get "sh: node: command not found" when running the system command.

```
system("node -v")
```

Update:

Not as nice as some of the suggestions below, but I managed to echo the command into a file and have it opened and executed in terminal:

```
system("echo node -v > ~/installation.command; chmod +x ~/installation.command; open ~/installation.command")
```

Comment: Do you definitely have a command line util installed called `node`? What happens when you try `node -v` in Terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looked into this a bit more.

The `nodejs` installer uses `/usr/local/bin`, which is not included in the `PATH` for applications launched from Finder:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

The directory is included in the `PATH` set for `bash` via `/etc/profile` & [path_helper](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/path_helper.8.html):

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Options:

- Just write `/usr/local/bin/node` instead of `node`.
- Tweak the `PATH` used by `NSTask` via the `environment` property.
- Use [setenv](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/setenv.3.html) to change the `PATH` for `system` — will also affect `NSTask`.
- Execute `bash` as a login shell. See the    [man       page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html)    for details.

Comment: Writing the path before running the command works easy enough, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
func shell(command: String) -> Int32 {
    let task = NSTask()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    task.arguments = ["bash", "-c", command]
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
}
```

So you can do `shell("node -v")` which I find more convenient:

Answer (score 2):

using [swift-commands](https://github.com/QiuZhiFei/swift-commands)

```swift
import Commands

Commands.Bash.run("node -v")
```

Answer (score 1):

> "sh: node: command not found"

Obviously, `node` is not an absolute path.

Sounds like you've made changes to `~/.bash_profile` or another file to include the location of `node` in the `PATH` [environment variable](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/environ.7.html).

`system` is launching `bash` using `sh -c`.

I forget what the rules are exactly, but `bash` will ignore at least some configuration files when executed this way. Presumably, your changes to `PATH` are not being read or applied.

> "env: node: No such file or directory"

Again, `node` is not an absolute path. `NSTask` doesn't use a shell, so any processes you execute will inherit your application's environment variables. In most cases, this means the default `PATH`.

If you need a custom environment for `NSTask`, grab the `environment` dictionary from `NSProcessInfo`, make your changes & then set `NSTask`'s `environment` property.