# Running Swift commands from a Mac app

Tags: swift, xcode, bash, macos, shell

I'm attempting to run a Swift script using the command line from my Swift-based Mac app.

I have the following class method, which takes in arguments, and runs the commands:

```
func shell(_ args: String...) -> Int32 {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    task.arguments = args
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
}
```

I'm able to execute commands such as the following successfully:

```
    shell("pwd")
    shell("ls")
    shell("swift")
```

`pwd` returns all the files in my app's build directory, as expected. This includes a `hello.swift` file that I manually added, which just prints "Hello, world!". Additionally, running `swift` does grant access to the Swift environment.

What I'm not having luck with is running commands such as:

`shell("swiftc hello.swift")`

Instead, I get the following error:

`env: swiftc hello.swift: No such file or directory`

It looks as though I'm facing a similar situation as these posts:

[Swift Process - execute command error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43266759/swift-process-execute-command-error)

[Running shell commands in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238366/running-shell-commands-in-swift?rq=1)

But, I'm not sure I fully understand all the implications therein for my specific situation.

Comment: Never knew Swift was a scripting language - much less had those capabilities. Always thought invoked the compiler, which is quite different than invoking a script. Always *knew* you could *compile* something in most any language using shell commands, but always thought the output of compiling wasn't a script. Bottom line? I think you are hoping to make an "Apple" into an "Orange". What makes you think there's anything like a "Swift scripting language"?

Comment: @dfd the "Apple" needs no conversion to your "Orange". Swift is perfectly suited as a scripting language and has been since version 1, as demonstrated [here](https://krakendev.io/blog/scripting-in-swift). It's also very powerful, since *Anything you can do with Foundation, you can put into a [swift] script."* Obviously, we've moved on from v1, but it's [still viable today](https://jblevins.org/log/swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify, before we begin, `swiftc` is used to compile a swift script into a binary. In contrast, calling `swift` with a swift script file, will interpret the given file.

> env: swiftc hello.swift: No such file or directory

Essentially, this is stating that the `env` binary is being passed two arguments: *swiftc* and *hello.swift* and doesn't know what to do with it.

```
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
```

I'm not sure why you're calling `env` here, but assuming I understand your goal correctly, we can use `bash` for the desired outcome.

Let's assume we have the following *script.swift* file

```
#!/usr/bin/swift
import Foundation

func shell(_ args: String...) -> Int32 {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
    task.arguments = ["-c"]
    task.arguments = task.arguments! + args
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
}

_ = shell("pwd")
_ = shell( "swift cmds.swift")
```

Instead of calling `env`, it's using `bash`. In order to pass a string to `bash` it requires the `-c` argument, which we prepended with

```
task.arguments = ["-c"]
task.arguments = task.arguments! + args
```

The end of the script can be seen calling the file *cmds.swift*. If we execute *script.swift* via the interpreter, it's not going to be able to call *cmds.swift* - essentially calling the interpreter from within itself!

So, we'll compile *script.swift* to a binary:

```
swiftc script.swift
```

This outputs a binary with the name *script*.

As we've seen, the binary calls *cmds.swift*, so let's create this with the following script code...

```
#!/usr/bin/swift  
import Foundation

print("Hello World\n")
```

Now if we execute the binary that we compiled, we'll see it successfully call the interpreted script and output the path (from pwd) and "Hello World", which came from the calling *cmds.swift*.